# How many periods of pipeline does an Intel Pentium Pro have?

Tags: cpu

At school we learned about the Intel Pentium processor. I read somewhere that the Intel Pentium was the first superscalar processor and had five periods of pipeline. My question leads to the Pentium Pro.

I read somewhere that the Pentium Pro has three Arithmetic Logic Units + a Floating Point Unit and all of these units have 14 periods of pipeline (three instructions per one tact). However I read elsewhere that it only has five periods of pipeline like the Pentium. I don't know which is true.

How many periods of pipeline does an Intel Pentium Pro have?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Pentium was the first *x86* processor that was superscalar, but it was far from being the first superscalar processor. The Pentium wasn't even the first *Intel* superscalar processor (that was the i960). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscalar for history.

Superscalar processors have multiple pipelines and these tend to have different lengths, so I'm not sure there's a simple answer to your question. Execution units tend to each have their own processing pipeline and then there is usually a common fetch/decode/despatch pipeline which feeds the various execution unit pipelines.

Comment: oh, thanks a lot .. This is sufficient answer for my question. Maybe why I read a little diferent information somewhere about that... That's just for my curiosity ...

Answer (score 3):

Ars Technica has a couple of good articles on the history of the Pentium architecture.

- [Part 1](http://arstechnica.com/old/content/2004/07/pentium-1.ars/)
- [Part 2](http://arstechnica.com/old/content/2004/07/pentium-2.ars/)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out some of the pdf's available here
http://www.agner.org/optimize/